# Timeout setting on asp.net handler after return

Tags: c#, ultidev

I have a Asp.net handler (.ashx) that is used fill a database on android, my handler is well optimized so it returns in 10 seconds, on android, the application uses the stream to write the rows during the download, my problem is that this writing is pretty slow, and after 3 minutes and 30 the socket goes in exception with "Connection reset". I tried a lot of timeout setting but none changed this behaviour. I am using Utlidev web server. Any idea of which timeout is? Using IIS Express (from VS2019) it works even after 20 minutes, so it is an issue of Ultidev setting.

Comment: Please consider getting additional error details from the Windows Event Log (Application) on the host system where UltiDev Web Server (UWS) runs. Also, if possible, run your server app in interactive UWS (http://www.ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postsm2833_UWS-Screenshots.aspx#post2833) - it logs quite a bit about its request processing and may provide insight into what is going on. To make it simple you may be able to right-click the app folder in Windows explorer and run it in AWS. Still, since not all "http.sys" settings are surfaced by UWS, solution may or may not exist.

Comment: using interactive UWS does not reset, thanks for suggestion

Comment: Next thing to try is to stop the UWS service and run it as a regular program (see here, 2nd bullet: http://ultidev.com/forums/yaf_postsm2903_Installation--Operations--Troubleshooting.aspx#post2903) to see whether that makes any difference (it is unlikely as it still should run ASP.NET host processes either as NETWORK_SERVICE or LOCAL_SYSTEM. You may want to change your app host to run as LOCAL_SYSTEM and see whether that helps, but that would expose the server to the world of malicious attacks with a high risk of takeover.

Comment: no change running it with "UWS Monitoring service", even the log does not specify the break of connection

Comment: I see that if I use UWS it sends "Content-Length", in other case doesn't, maybe it is because "allow response compression" is disabled? I will try to disable it on "Server explorer"

Comment: I can confirm, if I disable "Allow compression response" the connection will not reset after 3 minutes and it sends "Content-Lenght"